# Run service every 24 hours and stop after 5 times android code

Tags: java, android, service

How can i run an android service every 24 hours for 5 times and then don't run it again.
I have already created the service class and named it `ServiceActive.class` . How can i achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: no? can this help to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the alarm manager class to carry out tasks set in the future. this every time the alarm goes off, you can further its time by another 24 hours while reducing your counter by one. after the 5 counter decrements are done, you can just disable the alarm manager and thus never calling it again. i hope that helps you.

Comment: can you give me any reference or tutorial to this? i will really appreciate it

Comment: this is the documentation for alarm manager [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and a [tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html) and disabling here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820044/android-alarmmanager-and-service-question