# Android Camera Image Capture without button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera, surfaceview

Ok I have been having trouble implementing a camera application that is able to capture an image without the press of a button. Currently a working camera application but when the below code is commented out:

```
buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);

buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) { // <5>
    (1)    preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
  }
});*/
```

and replaced with a loop that just calls (1), the preview is never visible and causes the application to shutdown. Preview class is below:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;

import android.util.Log;

import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

import android.view.SurfaceView;

class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback { // 

  <1>
    private static final String TAG = "Preview";

  SurfaceHolder mHolder;  // <2>
  public Camera camera; // <3>

  Preview(Context context) {
    super(context);

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();  // <4>
    mHolder.addCallback(this);  // <5>
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS); // <6>
  }

  // Called once the holder is ready

  public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {  // <7>
    // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
    // to draw.
    camera = Camera.open(); // <8>
    try {
      camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);  // <9>

      camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() { // <10>
        // Called for each frame previewed
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {  // <11>
          Log.d(TAG, "onPreviewFrame called at: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
          Preview.this.invalidate();  // <12>
        }
      });
    } catch (IOException e) { // <13>
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  // Called when the holder is destroyed
  public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {  // <14>
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera = null;
  }

  // Called when holder has changed
  public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) { // <15>
    camera.startPreview();
  } 

}
```

Any ideas as to where to go from here and why this is occuring?

Comment: excuse horrendous formatting

Comment: what the actual your requirement ?

Comment: This is basically a small part of an application that I want to run autonomously, and capture a picture every 24hrs and upload to twitter.

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply looping over the line marked (1), then you are causing the UI thread to block. It will never be able to update the preview, or indeed do anything else with the UI until you are invited to force close your app.

If your goal is to be taking regular snapshots with the camera, then you need to be using a separate thread to trigger the photos actually being taken: e.g. a task which triggers regular callbacks to the UI thread.

An example of code which may serve your purpose (in terms of providing a timer on the non-ui thread) is [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html)

If you're wanting to do something else, then you'll need to describe the goal.

UPDATE:
Because you are wanting to use such a long time gap for taking photos, you'll want to use an [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). There is a [tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html) and [relevant other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820044/android-alarmmanager-and-service-question).

You'll need to create an activity which takes the photograph, and then set up the alarm manager to trigger that activity every 24 hours.
Using the alarm manager means that Android itself will take care of whether it is in sleep mode, you don't need to worry about your app being destroyed, which if you were running a timer in your own thread would kill the timer.

Comment: Basically I am running a sensor program and this activity will not be running for the vast majority of the time. Every 24 hours I want to take a picture and upload to twitter. This needs to occur without human interaction, if possible. Thanks for your help

Comment: With long time periods like that, you'll probably want to use  [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). There is an [example](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html) and [another post on the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820044/android-alarmmanager-and-service-question). I've updated my post with more details.

Comment: It would be great if you could accept an answer (either mine or iDroid's) so the question no longer appears as unanswered (and so one of us gets rep).

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I got your requirement. You should have to just try with to AlarmManager which reminds regarding your selected time. And while that service will call, You have to implement the code of to get Capture Image from the camera nothing else.

you can put the code that normally works in any camera app to capture image.

Just Call that code while the alarm is called(Your service is called).

Hope you got my point.

Feel free for the comments.

Comment: is My answer work for your code then accept it so it can help others.